# Javascript alternative of jQuery.ajax() - facing errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

This is the `JS Object`

```
var datas = {
    name: "xyz",
    age:21,
}

var datas2 = JSON.stringify(datas);
```

The below AJAx Request is passing datas correctly

```
 $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'two.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'html',
            data:{data:datas2}
        });
    });
```

**Response in the developer tools:**

```
Array
(
    [data] => {"name":"xyz","age":21}
)
```

Now tried with **Javascript AJAX Reuest**

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","two.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
xmlhttp.send(datas2);
```

**Response in the developer tools:**

```
Array
(
    [{"name":"xyz","age":21}] => 
)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I ma not sure if you send the same data in both cases. What do happen when using `xmlhttp.send({data:datas2});` ?

Comment: Well, you are passing `{data:datas2}` to jQuery but only `datas2` to `.send`. If you want to send the same data, you have to write `xmlhttp.send('data=' + datas2')`.

Comment: [This](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) might help you

Comment: @Mat When I tried this `xmlhttp.send({data:datas2});`, only [Object object] passes since its not stringified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending two different values. jQuery will convert the object `{data: datas2}` to the string

```
data={"name":"xyz","age":21}
```

whereas `xmlhttp.send(datas2)` will just send the string

```
{"name":"xyz","age":21}
```

That's a big difference! In the second case `{"name":"xyz","age":21}` is treated as parameter *name* instead of *value* which is what you see with the developer tools.

If you want to send the same payload, you have to do

```
xmlhttp.send('data=' + datas2')
```

Comment: Yup...thats what I missed, I actually tried that in a wrong way like `xmlhttp.send({data:datas2});`. thanx, its working now

Comment: Another doubt..hope you can help me with, `Jquery AJAX` is url encoding the datas being passed when I saw it in the developer tools.So I too used `encodeURIComponent()` which too encoded correctly, but even without encoding too, that worked. Why is that? Isnt url encoding necessary?

Comment: Not for POST requests since the data is not sent in the URL. However, if your data can contain special characters such as `&`, then you should probably still do it.